# How unique index internally works in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have read some articles and oracle documentation on unique and nonunique indexes. What I understood is Index is Index and constraint is constraint.

Constraint uses the index to ensure data integrity.
The primary key uses the unique or nonunique index to ensure that column is unique and not null.
The same goes for unique constrain.
But constraints can use a non-unique index if we want them deferrable.

The question comes for a unique index, it is just an index and I can not see any constraint associated with it so what is going on internally so the unique index won't allow for duplicate values, it is some internal semantics working as a constraint to ensure index uniqueness?

And let's say a unique index has the ability to be unique without any constraint then I want to understand the relation of constraints with indexes in every sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There really is no such thing as a nonunique entry in a B*Tree index. In a nonunique index, Oracle simply stores the rowid by appending it to the key as an extra column with a length byte to make the key unique. For example, an index such as CREATE INDEX I ON T(X,Y) is conceptually CREATE UNIQUE INDEX I ON T(X,Y,ROWID). In a unique index, as defined by you, Oracle does not add the rowid to the index key. In a nonunique index, you will find that the data is sorted first by index key values (in the order of the index key) and then by rowid ascending. In a unique index, the data is sorted only by the index key values".

Though unique, primary key constraints and unique indexes both help with uniqueness, their objectives differ.

A unique or primary key constraints are meant to enforce data integrity. They might create a unique index implicitly and then it uses unique index to maintain integrity or it can use nonunique index as the key enforcement. Anyway index (unique or nonunique) always used to support primary key.

A unique index serves to make data access efficient. Its primary purpose is to help performance, but it does maintain uniqueness as a corollary and primary key may use this.